# What is an elegant way to retry a method for specific HTTP code

Tags: error-handling, feign, spring-retry

Hi an a method annotated with @Retryable annotation

```
@Override
    @Retryable( value = FeignException.class, maxAttempts = 2, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 100))
    public Map<String, String> fetchMediaResponseFromMediaIds(Set<String> mediaIds) {
       try { code....

            } catch (TBadRequestException badRequestException){
                log.error("Bad Headers for Media Client Call with exception {} ",new SCXDealerSettingBadRequestException(InformationalErrorCode.DSS_ACC_BADREQUEST, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, ErrorConstants.REQUEST_HEADERS_MISSING),badRequestException);
            }
            catch (FeignException feignException){
                final TFeignErrorUtils.ErrorDetails errorDetails = getErrorDetailsOrNull(feignException.content());

                log.error("Error getting Media Urls from Media Client {} with details {}" ,feignException );
            }
            catch (Exception exception){
                log.error("Error getting Media Urls from Media Client  {} with exception" , GenericErrorCode.DSS_MEDIA_GENERIC,exception);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Retry Policy class

```
public class FeignExceptionServerErrorRetryPolicy implements RetryPolicy {
    @Override
    public boolean canRetry(RetryContext context) {
        Throwable lastThrowable = context.getLastThrowable();
        if (lastThrowable instanceof FeignException) {
            FeignException feignException = (FeignException) lastThrowable;
            int httpStatusCode = feignException.status();
            return String.valueOf(httpStatusCode).startsWith("5");
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public RetryContext open(RetryContext parent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void close(RetryContext context) {

    }

    @Override
    public void registerThrowable(RetryContext context, Throwable throwable) {

    }
}
```

I want this retry method to run only when feignException is a server error ie 5xx error code . How can i do that without using if and else. I have retry policy defined but not sure how to inject it in the methods retry .